# Review Bank Page Issue on Analyse (again) button

Tags: civibanking

[image]
When I click Analyse (again) button on the review page i.e.(civicrm/banking/review?s_list=45)
I get 500 service unavailable error in console 
[image]

```
 https://www.example.com/civicrm/ajax/rest 500 (Service unavailable (with message))
  send @ jquery.js:9664
  ajax @ jquery.js:9215
  (anonymous) @ crm.ajax.js?p52hox:143
  CRM.api @ crm.ajax.js?p52hox:152
  analysePayment @ review?s_list=45:752 
  onclick @ review?s_list=45:685
```

The code at analysePayment@review?s_list=45:752 is

```
  CRM.api('BankingTransaction', 'analyselist', query,
    {success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
        if (!data['is_error']) {
          // remove 'execute' bit from URL before reload
          var newURL = window.location.href.replace(reload_regex, '');
          if (window.location.href == newURL) {
            window.location.reload(false);
          } else {
            window.location = newURL;
          }
        } else {
          cj('<div title="Fout"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left;"></span>' + data['error_message'] + '</div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              Ok: function() {
                window.location = window.location.href.replace(reload_regex, '');
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

While debugging the above issue, I have traced it back to the below function
which you can find it here in github
https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/9dc6bdcc486753f70948edfd4ea36df0eb9d2f86/extension/CRM/Banking/Matcher/Engine.php
and the exact code where I think the issue is $continue value turns out to be 1 and which results in return value to be false since it does not enter the if(!$continue) condition

```
 foreach ($matchers as $matcher) {
          try {
            // run matchers to generate suggestions
            $logger->setTimer('matcher');
            $continue = $this->matchPlugin( $matcher, $context );
            $logger->logTime("Matcher [{$matcher->getPluginID()}]", 'matcher');
            if (!$continue) {
              $lock->release();
              $logger->logTime("Matching of btx [{$btx_id}]", 'matcher');
              return true;
            }
```

Now I need to find out a way to make it true so I can see options to match contributions
The matcher I am using is
https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/9dc6bdcc486753f70948edfd4ea36df0eb9d2f86/configuration_database/matcher/default/EnglishDefaults.json
I think this is where I need to alter json so that $continue value turns out to be false,but unsure how I can alter it and what does each key value pair does specifically.

```
 /**
   * Run this BTX through the matchers
   *
   * @param CRM_Banking_BAO_BankTransaction $btx
   * @param bool $override_processed   Set this to TRUE if you want to re-match processed transactions.
   *                                    This will destroy all records of the execution!
   */
  public function match( $btx_id, $override_processed = FALSE ) {
    // TODO: timeout is 30s - do we need a setting here?
    $lock_timeout = 30.0;
    $lock = CRM_Utils_BankingSafeLock::acquireLock('org.project60.banking.tx'.'-'.$btx_id, $lock_timeout);
    if (empty($lock)) {
      error_log("org.project60.banking - couldn't acquire lock. Timeout is $lock_timeout.");
      return false;
    }

    // load btx
    $btx = new CRM_Banking_BAO_BankTransaction();
    $btx->get('id', $btx_id);

    if (!$override_processed) {
      // don't match already executed transactions...
      $processed_status_id = banking_helper_optionvalueid_by_groupname_and_name('civicrm_banking.bank_tx_status', 'Processed');
      $ignored_status_id = banking_helper_optionvalueid_by_groupname_and_name('civicrm_banking.bank_tx_status', 'Ignored');
      if ($btx->status_id == $processed_status_id || $btx->status_id == $ignored_status_id) {
        // will not match already executed transactions
        $lock->release();
        return true;
      }
    }

    // reset the BTX suggestion list
    $btx->resetSuggestions();

    // reset the cache / context object
    $context = new CRM_Banking_Matcher_Context( $btx );
    $logger = CRM_Banking_Helpers_Logger::getLogger();

    // run through the list of matchers
    $logger->setTimer('matching');
    // run through the list of matchers
    $all_matchers = $this->getMatchers();
    if (empty($all_matchers)) {
      CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(ts("No matcher plugins configured!"), ts('No processors'), 'alert');
    } else {
      foreach ($all_matchers as $weight => $matchers) {
        foreach ($matchers as $matcher) {
          try {
            // run matchers to generate suggestions
            $logger->setTimer('matcher');
            $continue = $this->matchPlugin( $matcher, $context );
            $logger->logTime("Matcher [{$matcher->getPluginID()}]", 'matcher');
            if (!$continue) {
              $lock->release();
              $logger->logTime("Matching of btx [{$btx_id}]", 'matcher');
              return true;
            }
            // check if we can execute the suggestion right aways
            $abort = $this->checkAutoExecute($matcher, $btx);
            if ($abort) {
              $logger->logDebug("Matcher [{$matcher->getPluginID()}] executed automatically.");
              $lock->release();
              $logger->logTime("Matching of btx [{$btx_id}]", 'matcher');
              return false;
            }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            $matcher_id = $matcher->getPluginID();
            error_log("org.project60.banking - Exception during the execution of matcher [$matcher_id], error was: ".$e->getMessage());
            $lock->release();
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $btx->saveSuggestisons();
    // set the status
    $newStatus = banking_helper_optionvalueid_by_groupname_and_name('civicrm_banking.bank_tx_status', 'Suggestions');

    $btx->status_id = $newStatus;
    $btx->setStatus($newStatus);

    $lock->release();
    $context->destroy();
    $logger->logTime("Matching of btx [{$btx_id}]", 'matcher');
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: You may want to add this to the Extension's project page at https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/releases

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, yes I have added it,but I now seem may be something is missing with respect to matcher plugin , I might have added it.  https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/issues/190

Comment: This is ually caused by a misconfiguration of one of the matchers. You can probably see the error in the logs or in the netwerk tab on the response of the ajax call